# HTML IF statements in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

i have this js code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.animate_hoverCard').tooltipster({
        interactive: true,
        content: 'Loading...',
        contentCloning: false,
        contentAsHTML: true,
        animation: 'fade',
        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
            // we'll make this function asynchronous and allow the tooltip to go ahead and show the loading notification while fetching our data.
            continueTooltip();
            origin.tooltipster('content', '<div class="hovercard"> <div> <div class="display-pic"> <div class="cover-photo"> <div class="display-pic-gradient"></div><img src="dp.jpg"> </div><div class="profile-pic"> <div class="pic"> <img src="avatar.jpg" title="Profile Image"> </div><div class="details"> <ul class="details-list"> <li class="details-list-item"> <p> <span class="glyph glyph-home"></span> <span> Also Lives in <a href="#">Chennai</a> <a href="#">TamilNadu</a></span> </p></li><li class="details-list-item"> <p> <span class="glyph glyph-work"></span> <span> Founder at <a href="#">CodeDodle</a></span> </p></li></ul> </div></div></div><div class="display-pic-gradient"></div><div class="title-container"> <a class="title" href="#" title="Visit Page">Tamil Selvan</a> <p class="other-info">2 followers</p></div><div class="info"> <div class="info-inner"> <div class="interactions"> <a href="#" class="btn">Add Friend</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Follow</a> </div></div></div></div></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

I want to know how to add HTML if statements like this `<!-- IF something -->(my code)<!-- ELSE --> &nbsp; <!-- ENDIF -->`

Is it possible?

Comment: HTML doesn't have `if` statements. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_comments_in_JScript

Comment: Are you trying to embed the [if statements](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) into the tooltip itself? Or are you trying to not have the tooltip to show for certain browsers?

Comment: @ chris: Yes.. i trying to insert the if into the tooltip. On this line:

 origin.tooltipster('content', '<div class="hovercard"> <div> <div class="display-pic">  etc..

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have if else statements like PHP or other programming languages. Although, you can use if else statements in Javascript to perform certain tasks.

```
if (hour < 18) {
    greeting = "Good day";
} else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
}
```

Here is a great resource to learn more about if else statements more indepth. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language. This means it has no `if` statements. **It is not possible in HTML**

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9433448), the user wanted to do the same thing as you.

What you could do is use Javascript for your `if/else` statements and use `document.write()` to add content

Check out the following links to pages on MDN:

- [`if/else` statements in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) - Used for selecting elements and writing to the page

---

### Here is how you would implement this

Let us say you want to write inside a `div` with an ID of `my_div`. You could use the following code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('my_div')
```

This will select the `div` with ID of `my_div`. It is the equivalent to the CSS selector `#my_div`

Now to write to that div:

```
div.innerHTML = 'Some text'
```

View the Code Snippet below for an example:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('my_div')

if (true) {
 div.innerHTML = 'True!'
}
else {
 div.innerHTML = 'False!'
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Comment: But how i can attach the document.write code to my code?

Comment: I am updating my answer, check it out. And why the downvote?

Comment: Using <script type="text/javascript" (src="MyFile.js if external)>

Answer (score -1):

No, HTML is a markup language: it has no `if` statements.